# What would happen if the electric field was cut to a cyclotron half-way?

Tags: electromagnetism, accelerator-physics

After accelerating say a proton, half way, if the alternating electric field was cut, would the proton maintain a perpetual circular motion at the same radius?

I know that any charged particle moving in a magnet field radiates energy, so would the proton spiral towards the center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would spiral towards the centre, much like it was thought of electrons around the atom at the beginning of the 20th century.

You can actually calculate the power emitted with the Larmor formula.